# Wired Ethernet Connection Settings are not changed

Tags: ethernet, connection, wired

I have a verison of

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

first I disconnect my ethertnet cable and linux pop up some info about wired connection has been gone then Linux ask me to close wired connection and I didn't think there will be a problem about:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sdpK.png

now I cannot open the connection it doesn't give me allow to do this, and I searched it and I did many things to fix this but it didn't work, and also I replug my ethernet cable but never display any wired connection.
How can I solve this, my solutions really depleted.
Any suggestion or answer I will be appreciate.